# Excel formulas show zero in a part of a particular spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

My Excel spreadsheet seems to have a bug.  In one section, in one tab, the calculations stopped working.  There is no error, the cells are properly formatted, but the formulas do not calculate.  The cell formulas include simple add and subtract calculations as well functions and if then statements.  Manual and automatic calculations settings have no impact. However, when I highlight a formula, copy it and paste it into the same cell the formula works?  Since this is client work and the answers in the summary page depend on proper calculations, searching for cells which do not work is not a feasible solution.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like something similar that I've done before. It happens to me when I change the formatting of the cell. Excel won't then just start working until you `refresh each cell`. I usually press `F2 then enter`, which refreshes the cell.

Comment: Because you mention that the manual and automatic calculations don't impact this, I wonder if you could provide an actual formula example of a cell with the 0 result

Comment: This did not work

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer which is to replace the = sign with an new = sign before each formula.  By coincidence, I found a reference to this in a post to a different question posted in 2012 which I have pasted below.  This seems to be a an issue which has been around for awhile.  Disheartening, since I do not have a system to recheck if all of my formulas are still working.

> This often happens with very large and complex spreadsheets. Here are
>   some workarounds you could try:
>
> CTRL + ALT + SHIFT + F9 to recheck all formula dependencies and then
>   recalculate all formulas. Select any blank cell, press F2 and then
>   Enter. Re-enter = :
>
> Select cells that contain formulas you'd like to update Press CTRL+H.
>   Find what: = Replace with: = This may take a while depending on the
>   size of your workbook. Save your file before attempting.

Also the suggestion to copy and repaste the entire sheet worked.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try if you can tell at a glance if it's all working, is to create a new sheet, and A1=OldsheetA1. See what happens then.

Alternatively, since copy-pasting works, copy the entire sheet, and paste it again.

3rd potential solution: Try to save the sheet. I've had calculation issues in the past that saving and reopening solved

Answer (score 0):

Turn Automatic calculations back on:

[image]

Select Formulas > Calculation Options < Automatic

Comment: No impact on issue